# How to parallelize a task in which there are requests to a db?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate

I have a kotlin application and a Spring JdbcTemplate and a Hikary connection pool with two connections.

And I have the task that is a good candidate for parallel execution.

It's a list of strings:

```
List<String>
```

which turns into list of lists after splitting:

```
List<List<String>>
```

and i can take its chunks and make sql queries to db separately. All chunks are independent of each other.

The result of work of these subtasks is total list of responses.

The question is - how to prevent degradation of performance and avoid wait connection time out?

May be exsits better way to hadle faster large list intended for db queries...

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you want to do with `List<List<String>>` and how it is related to a single database call?

Comment: I will split it on chunks. For example: I have list and its size is 1000. I take sublists with size of 100 and make 10 calls to db with that sublists. I want to make all calls in parallel. And after that combine all responses in one total list. In java i can do it with parallelStream or with complitableFeatures. In kotlin i can do it with async/awaitAll.

Comment: Are you sure about your data structure? I can imagine a Map<String, List<String>> but I don't get why it might be useful for you a List<List<String>>.

Comment: In input a take large list of Strings - List<String>. But after splitting it turns into list of lists - List<List<String>>. Maybe I expressed myself incorrectly)

Comment: Do you split your list just to reduce the workload of your SQL ? if so, maybe it is better to provide some more info about your query as well.

Comment: I believe you do not need to save the split inside another list. Are you inserting into a table? insert batch might be helpful because it uses just one connection and all the insert queries would be considered as a transaction. either all committed or rollback

Comment: Yes. I want to reduce sql workload. Now i have input list of about 1000 strings with ids. And the responses of that is recods with 10 columns per resord. And I want to make a reserve for the future. If there are more of that string with ids.

Comment: Its select queries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243416/discussion-between-shila-mosammami-and-user2625402).